Ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
Я пытаюсь отправить себе на почту письмо. Все 2 почты мои. Использую os, email, smtplib, а также telebot.
Код:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test_message(messagep):
   message = "WORKED!"
   bot.send_message(messagep.chat.id, test(message=message))


def test(message):
   sender = "demian.spb2013@yandex.ru"
   orders = "orders@demonstudio.ru"
   password = os.getenv("app_password_email")

   print(message)

   server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.yandex.ru", 587)
   server.starttls()

   try:
       server.login(sender, password)
       server.sendmail(sender, orders, message)

       return "The message was sent successfully!"
   except Exception as _ex:
       return f"{_ex}\nCheck your login or password please!"

Ошибка:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример


Полный трейс ошибки - прямо в вопрос. Полный! 2) Нет ли у вас выше приведённого фрагмента кода переменной test или ещё одной функции test, которая ничего не возвращает?


Нет, нету) Спасибо за вопрос!

Ну тогда хотя бы полный стек-трейс, потому что сейчас только гадать, на какой строке кода эта ошибка выходит. Могу сванговать, что os.getenv("app_password_email") выдаёт None, но это не точно. Ошибка может быть в любом месте, без трейса только гадать.

У меня без этого кода было всё нормально.

Стойте, вы правы - я вывел значение password и мне выдало None

У меня всё сработало, после того, как я убрал os.getenv у password. Мне подсказали в комментариях)

Ну либо нужно задать эту переменную в окружении, она видимо не задана.
